# Total amount in service order to be asked on paypal as well? How?

Tags: paypal

Sorry for the confusing title. Here's my problem -- I am using contact form 7 and I have added paypal in my checkout option but how will it able to record the total amount of the service ordered and be asked for payment? Because it just redirects to paypal with a fixed rate that I put upon creating the button. Can anyone help? Thanks.

PS: This is an example.
If someone wants to avail the service on my site and they want an additional service, they select that service and it will add to the total charge and upon clicking the pay now button, it will charge the total amount on paypal then they pay.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your page dynamically populate the amount prior to redirecting the buyer over to PayPal.  To be able to do this, you would need to create a non hosted clear text button.  Another option would be to create a buy now button and enter in the amount as 0.00, this would prompt the buyer to update the amount before they proceed to make the payment on the payPal page.

Comment: The 2nd option -- would it mean that it would make them put the supposed total themselves?

Comment: With the second option, Yes.